# Dialogbox restrict input to numbers only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here a working code about a dialogbox that lets the user input something but i am having problems on implementing my function that only accepts numerical input.

Dialogbox Code:

HTML:

```
<p>You have entered: <span id="buttonoutput"></span></p>
<a id="opendialog" data-role="button">Sample Dialogbox</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).delegate('#opendialog', 'click', function() {

  $('<div>').simpledialog2({
    mode: 'button',
    headerText: 'Hmm?',
    headerClose: true,
    buttonPrompt: 'Please Type Something',
    buttonInput: true,
    buttons : {
      'OK': {
        click: function () { 
          $('#buttonoutput').text($.mobile.sdLastInput);
        }
      },
    }
  })
})
```

My input restricting function:

```
            //only accepts numerical input
    function isNumberKey(evt){
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
        return true;
    }
```

My problem is how do i call the function within the inputbox of the dialogbox. 
Any help or advice will be gladly accepted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you're using HTML5 you can use <input type="number" name="someid" /> to restrict the input field only to numbers

Comment: provide a working fiddle pls

Comment: i need to place the restriction within my jquery code but i don't know how.

Comment: this is where i got the dialogbox code with a working demo http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/button.html

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to use something like [this input mask](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). At any rate, if you want to go with your custom function, you will probably want to make use of the [.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) function on your input:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#inputbox').keydown (function () {
 $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
});
```

This will essentially replace all non-numerics. Use it in your `keydown` event.